# @Autowired annotation in spring

Tags: spring, annotations

i am relatively new in spring and i have problems with understanding fundamentals of spring mvc..

My controller

```
 @Controller
public class HomeController {  

private ContactManager contactManager;

@Autowired
public void setContactManager(ContactManager contactManager) {
    this.contactManager = contactManager;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
    List<Contact> listContact = contactManager.list();
    model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
    model.setViewName("home");
    return model;
 }
 ...
```

Contact ManagerImpl, and implementation of interface method

```
public class ContactManagerImpl implements ContactManager {
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
  ...
```

ContactManager

```
public interface ContactManager {
public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact);
public void delete(int contactId);
public Contact get(int contactId);
public List<Contact> list();
 }
```

And root-context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="sec"/>
</bean>

<bean id="managmentService" class="spring.contact.impl.model.ContactManagerImpl">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

My problem is that i get error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of
type [spring.contact.api.ContactManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1    
bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

And of course the problem is with @Autowired annotations. How can i fix it ? When i removed @Autowired annotations i get another error: NullPointerException (manager in HomeController).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller should be..

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {  

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("managmentService")
    private ContactManager contactManager;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Contact> listContact = contactManager.list();
        model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
        model.setViewName("home");
        return model;
     }
     ...
```

In your configuration add also `<context:annotation-config />`that is used in order to be able to use @Autowired annotation.

---

An example of `<context:annotation-config />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>
   <!-- bean definitions go here -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Ok, so i introduced changes and i get error associated with <context:annotation-config />, like this: "ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (main) Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 21 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 34; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'."

Comment: Have you added the correct namespaces of elements "context"?

Comment: @volly let me know if everything works fine, in order to help you better and close this topic.

Comment: it works ;) thanks, now i need to understand why it works with these changes in the code...

Comment: The `@Qualifier` is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Move the @Autowired annotation to the declaration for ContactManager.

You won't need the setter, delete it.

Comment: I removed setter and changed to: @Autowired    
    private ContactManager contactManager;  and it did not help.

Comment: What do you think this would accomplish differently?